# Is it possible to grab information such as city based on the center of the mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView` and want to grab the cities name based on the center of the `MKMapView`. I do not want to drop any pins or annotations at all. Just automatically grab the data based on center of `MKMapView` location. I know there is this method '[placemarkName locality]'. But is there a way without using a placemark?

Comment: Why don't you want to use placemarks?

Comment: I believe his "Use case" is to get a general idea of which city the user is viewing without dropping a pin.  Maybe to update a label below the map.

Comment: Agreed. But I suspect he's conflating "placemarks" (which are abstract objects related to various points of interest) and "annotations" (which are what you add to a map so a pin (an "annotation view") can be rendered). When you use `CLGeocoder` to get the array of placemarks, that doesn't mean you have to add annotations on the map for them. So, to get the city, he just needs to fetch the array of placemarks from `reverseGeocodeLocation`, grab the city name from that, and then let the placemarks fall out of scope, adding nothing to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a `reverseGeocodeLocation` (effective iOS 5+) from the `centerCoordinate` of the map view. For example, I could do something like:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;

CLGeocoder *coder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[coder reverseGeocodeLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:center.latitude longitude:center.longitude] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    self.cityLabel.text = [[placemarks firstObject] locality];
}];
```

This admittedly, returns an array of placemarks, but you don't have to do anything with them after you extract the city's name.